# image optimize Issue

Tags: media, files

I have installed [S3 File System](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) module, and all image files are served from AWS S3 bucket. The images served from S3 are not compressed. How to compress those images?

Following is the message I get when checking with page speed:

> Compressing
>   https://example.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s3fs-public/test.jpg could
>   save 22.4KiB (26% reduction).

Answer (score 0):

When uploading images into Drupal, those are uploaded as it is and not compressed. To compress them you can check [Image Optimize (or ImageAPI Optimize)](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize) Module.

Another solution is to add custom code in your custom module, which will compress image before a record is inserted into `file_managed` table, check code below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_presave().
 */
function [MODULE_NAME]_file_presave($file) {
  if (!empty($file->filemime) && (strpos('image', $file->filemime) >= 0)) {
    $compressed = _[MODULE_NAME]_compress_image($file->uri, $file->uri, 75);
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to compress images while uploading.
 *
 * @param string $source_url
 *   Source image URL.
 *
 * @param string $destination_url
 *   Destination image URL.
 *
 * @param string $quality
 *   Percentage of Image quality to compress.
 */
function _[MODULE_NAME]_compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {
  $source_url = drupal_realpath($source_url);
  $destination_url = drupal_realpath($destination_url);

  $info = getimagesize($source_url);

  if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
  }
  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
  }
  elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }

  //save file
  imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);

  //return destination file
  return $destination_url;
}
```

**NOTE:** Change **[MODULE_NAME]** with your module name.

Answer (score 0):

Give [reSmush.it image style optimizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/resmushit) a try. It allows you to set which image styles should be optimized. It uses the excellent and free https://www.resmush.it/ API.

reSmush.it module works perfectly with [s3fs](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) (we are using it on all projects as well).